# WebBrowser.Navigate just... Isn't

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have this code:

```
private void goButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    web.Navigate(loginURL.Text + "/auth/login");
}
```

I have the browser showing, and it's just not navigating... It doesn't navigate etc.

The URL is valid.

Comment: It definitely does. Need more information to help you.

Comment: Is this Windows Forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.aspx) is your friend. Make sure you have the 'http://' prefix and try using the `Navigate(Uri url)` overload.

```
// Navigates to the given URL if it is valid. 
private void Navigate(String address)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(address)) 
         return;

    if (address.Equals("about:blank")) 
         return;

    if (!address.StartsWith("http://") && !address.StartsWith("https://"))
    {
        address = "http://" + address;
    }
    try
    {
        webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(address));
    }
    catch (System.UriFormatException)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle `DocumentCompleted` event of web browser.

Go through following code:

```
  private void goButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
      wb.AllowNavigation = true;

      wb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_DocumentCompleted);

      wb.Navigate(loginURL.Text + "/auth/login");

              }

    private void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
      WebBrowser wb = sender as WebBrowser;
      // wb.Document is not null at this point
    }
```

Comment: How does this relate to the question at all? The OP says it isn't navigating.. while your answer shows what to do once it has navigated..